# Array of channels

Tags: go, channel

I have an assignment to use arrays of channels.

I do not understand. Why this does not work?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func run() {
    chann[0] <- 1
}

var chann = make([]chan int, 2)

func main() {
    go run()
    obj := <- chann[0]
    fmt.Println(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have initialized the array of channels, but not the channels themselves.

As for why it deadlocks; this is due to the fact that a channel value that has not been initalised, or has been set to nil will always block. (See this [article](http://dave.cheney.net/tag/golang-3))

Comment: Thank You. For some reason I thought make intializes all elements too